# Cannot see the context menu to get drill-down options or to change colors in AWS Quicksight charts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am new to AWS QuickSight and I am trying to create a simple bar chart, but I want to apply different color to the bars. Although the AWS documentation details the step to change colors(here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/changing-visual-colors.html) it does not work for me. On clicking the bars I don't get the context menu as mentioned in AWS docs.

Similarly, I tried to drill down with sample data sets available, I did not get the menu with drill down options. I followed the steps as detailed in AWS docs.

Can someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with this for quite some time, before I spotted there are tiny 'drill up' and 'drill down' icons on the chart canvas. I guess they changed the interface but didn't update the docs yet.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Syscall take another look. It is an answer

Comment: Thank you @Zoe, and sorry. I've retracted the flag (I'm not the downvoter).